# How do I input my own headset rotation and position values for steamvr to process and use in game?

Tags: python, virtual-reality, steam, steamvr

I am trying to make a Steam VR compatible headset, I am strapping a Nintendo Switch joycon to the headset so I can track the rotation of the headset, but I can't find a way to somehow input the values of like headset rotation or controller position into Steam VR every frame.

I found this python library that can get the rotation and position of a Switch joycon, it works, but I still can't find a way to input the values into steam without using a headset like an Oculus to begin with.